# How can Downloading a big fIle from Telegram bot API

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Ok, I know in telegram bot API we can get the file_id and send it to `getFile` method and it will give us the file path so we can download it with an URL.

BUT it has a maximum limit of the file size of 20MB for each file.

Here is my question:

**How can [this bot](https://t.me/GetPublicLinkBot) bypass the size limitation?**

Personally wouldn't believe that until tested it with a 200MB sized file and it worked very fast. I want to make one like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume, they bypass this limit by using client api, where [getFile](https://core.telegram.org/method/upload.getFile) method have no size restrictions.

There must be another, "private" bot, that use telegram client api. Public bot just sends `file_id` (or whole message with attached file by calling [forwardMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forwardmessage)) to private bot, which do actual work of downloading files.

Comment: that should be it.

Comment: What do you mean by "private" bot?

Comment: @SemyonVyskubov, some appication that use telegram's client api, and can't be accesed by anything and anyone other than "public bot"(which use telegram's bot api and communicates to bot end user's).